# Conversion to a Singleton Class with Parameter

Tags: c#, thread-safety, singleton

Hi Guys am trying to convert a generic class into a `Singleton` class by using the thread safe approach.

I have the basic structure of my singleton class however am a bit confused on what way would be best to pass my `param` i.e. `ITest` and set the values of the properties within it?

```
public class TestClass
{
    public string property1 { get;set; }
    public string property2 { get;set; }

    public TestClass(ITest test)
    {
        property1 = test.GetProp1();
        property2 = test.GetProp2();
    }
}
```

Singleton Approach

```
public sealed class TestClass
{
    private TestClass() { }
    private static readonly object padlock = new object();
    private static TestClass _instance = null;
    public static TestClass Instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock (padlock)
            {
                if (_instance == null)
                {
                    _instance = new TestClass();
                }

                return _instance;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From [Jon Skeet's blog](https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Singleton): "Most commonly, singletons don't allow any parameters to be specified when creating the instance - as otherwise a second request for an instance but with a different parameter could be problematic"

Comment: @AFriend what do you suggest then? I don't want to create a `Static` class which is not thread safe :(

Comment: In your real scenario, what do those properties actually do? Could they be replaced by some configuration?

Comment: @AFriend the idea behind it is to be able to have access to the property values globally without creating a static class.

Comment: What's wrong with a static class? What does this singleton attempt offer you that a configuration manager doesn't? If you explain your initial problem and your ideal solution then maybe someone can better point you in the right direction.

Comment: This is [XY Problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Comment: @AFriend I am using Asp.Net Core so configuration manager is not an option. I get configurations and write them to my custom class so that they can be accessed.